# Sort array on string value (locale) in Realm - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, sorting, realm

I am trying to sort realm objects. The following code sorts allSongs correctly on title with the letters A-Z.

```
self.allSongs = realm.objects(Song.self).sorted("_title")
```

The thing is that I need to include Å, Ä and Ö (locale). The following code works. It sorts the songs correctly.

```
realm.objects(Song.self).sort {
    $0.title.compare($1.title, locale: swedish) == .OrderedAscending
}
```

The problem is that I cannot assign the result to my array of songs. This line gives me an error: "Cannot assign result of type [Song] to type Results".

```
self.allSongs = realm.objects(Song.self).sort {
    $0.title.compare($1.title, locale: swedish) == .OrderedAscending
}
```

Is there a way to cast it to the correct type?

Answer (score 1):

Realm doesn't natively allow locale-sensitive sorting (see issue [realm/realm-cocoa#2004](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2004)). The sort you're using is an in-memory one defined by the Swift standard library (see [`SequenceType.sort()`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/protocol/SequenceType/#func-generator-element_-comparable-sort)) rather than the Realm one (see [`Results.sorted(_:)`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Results.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift7Results6sorteduRd__s12SequenceTypeWd__9Generator7Element_zVS_14SortDescriptorrFqd__GS0_x_)).

You won't be able to re-assign or cast or convert a `Swift.Array` to a `RealmSwift.Results`.

If you want to benefit from `Results` features like auto-updating and lazy loading, you'll need to store a normalized string on your model to sort by using Realm's sort. You could store both your normal string along with a "normalized" version in your data model, where you perform the case folding before storing the value in Realm, perhaps using [CFStringTransform](http://nshipster.com/cfstringtransform/). You could then search on that string (also normalizing your search input).

Comment: Too bad there is no such functionality, but thanks anyway!